# check all globally installed npm packages with volta

Tags: npm, volta

I want to check all installed npm packages globally with volta.

Before volta, I usually used `npm-check-updates` with the command `ncu --global`.
With volta, this does not work anymore.

What is the best way to check and update all packages installed globally with volta?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of volta is to have the globally installed toolchains available for different projects ... which use different versions of the same tools. In every project, you can pin a specific version of a tool via `volta pin`.

Then, depending on the project folder you are in, the "pinned" tool version is used when run from a command prompt, not the most current one. So it does not really make sense to install the newest tools globally.

More: https://docs.volta.sh/guide/understanding

Comment: My use case is to use global package as CLI tools (for example I use *http-server* to quick start a server from any directory), I want to get them up to date simply like I do with ubuntu packages for example

Comment: The 'default version' should be what you search for. You can do `volta install http-server@latest` and it should always use the latest version. Unless you are in a project that has pinned a different version. No need to manually update, i guess.